# I have 2 different order table. How to increase the order_id depends on order nr

Tags: mysql, sql

I have those 2 order tables, `Orderone` and `Ordertwo`.

In both table auto increment the `order_id`.

Is it possible in any way to increase the `order_id` like this:

- first order in `Orderone` table will have id: 1
- then second order came into Ordertwo will have id: 2
- third order came into Ordertwo will have id: 3
- and maybe again order nr 4 will came into Orderone table so it will have id: 4

And so on - it checks into both tables and increase the id number as 1 table?

Comment: No.  This is not (easily) possible (you can do it using triggers).  It sounds like you have one orders table, not two.

Comment: why have two order tables here, not one?  design here needs to be challenged.

Comment: If you do need two order tables like this...create a third table that controls the orderID and have orderone and ordertwo reference that table.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I am using two order tables for for incoming orders through other shop system, and one for my own orders and i am handle the orders totally different, i just need the order_id for each to make assign status in new table but in the new table i just need to increase order_id even if it comes throug orderone or ordertwo.

@Twelfth i was thinking same way, just wanted to know if there maybe was a better solution. Anyway thanks a lot ! :)